# How to use composer package requiring assets in a restricted folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, composer-php, assets

I'm using a composer package (maximebf/debugbar) but it uses assets located in [site]/vendor/maximebf/debugbar/src/DebugBar/Resources. The problem is that this folder is supposed to be unreachable to the client since there's an .htaccess file in /vendor with the rule "Deny from all".

I could make an exception an specifically allow this folder, but I would be forced to do so for every package having assets like this.

Is there a proper way to make it work without forcing myself to create too many specific rules ?

Edit: these assets are .js and .css files

Sorry for my english :/

Comment: Having an `.htaccess` in the specific directory will override your root `.htaccess` (if your settings allow overrides) without making it too "messy". Some composer packages may actually come with one out of the box.

Comment: What bothers me is that Composer doesn't automatically handle theses cases. I don't want to have to add specific rules each time I update my packages or I deploy the app. There might be a way, but this will be enough for now. Thanks :)

Comment: I would think composer doesn't handle it because it's ran at the command line and doesn't really know what the underlying webserver would be in a production server (or if there is one at all).